# Craft 3 replacement for the Craft 2 fileCache component?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm upgrading a plugin from Craft 2 to Craft 3 and it looks like the `fileCache` component is no more.

What has replaced it in Craft 3?

Answer (score 1):

So, that will quite literally be the `cache` class then... sheesh, what a day this is.